# Populate another drop down list with data from database and insert into another database

Tags: php

I have created a dropdown list on each click of drop down another drop down list appears from [u]drop1[/u] database. Below is the code of the same:

**dropdown1.php**

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function showUser(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","drop2.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select a plan:</option>
    <option value="1">Dedicated</option>
    <option value="2">VPS</option>

    </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

    </body>
    </html>

**drop2.php:**

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM drop WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

/*echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

<th>plan1</th>
<th>plan2</th>

</tr>";*/
  echo "Plan";
  echo "<select>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

   echo "<option>" . $row['plan1'] . "</option>";
   echo "<option>" . $row['plan2'] . "</option>";

  }
//echo "</table>";
echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The above code works perfectly fine for shown the proper dropdown.
Now i want to insert the second dropdown value in another database.
And i am quite stuck in that.  :(

Answer (score 0):

It's no different than inserting into the same database, except you will connect like:

```
$con2 = mysqli_connect('localhostOrServerName','root','','otherDatabaseName');
```

Then you refer to the second database via $con2:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con2,$insert_sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
 $needInsert = false;
 $query = 'INSERT INTO table(plan1, plan2) VALUES ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
     $needInsert = true;
     $query .= "('{$row['plan1']}','{$row['plan2']}'),";

     echo "<option>" . $row['plan1'] . "</option>";
     echo "<option>" . $row['plan2'] . "</option>";
 }

 if ($needInsert)
 {
     $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
     mysqli_select_db($con,"another_db");
     mysqli_query($con,$query);
 }
```

I recommend you to use PDO extension instead of mysqli because it automatically sanitize data before insert into database. Otherwise, you have to sanitize `$row['plan1']` and `$row['plan2']` like this:

```
 mysql_real_escape_string($row['plan1']);
 mysql_real_escape_string($row['plan2']);
```